Laravel :: Option select fill input
I need help for selected option(option database and are data from the same table)
          <option selected value="-1">Open this select menu</option>
          @foreach($itens2 as $iten2)
           <option class="form-control" value="{{$iten2->id}}"> {{$iten2->nome}}</option>
         @endforeach 

and depending on what I choose, those options fill in the data within the input
For example, I want to show the data and email in the input (email).
 <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

What is the best way to overcome this?
Thanks!

Sorry I think I don't understand the question. It shouldn't be hard to achieve any kind of show, hide, replace data in a form using Javascript. What's the issue you're having?

What function can I use to fetch data from the database depending on what I select in the option.

You want to reduce the number of queries to the database if posible so I would send all the fields to the view and only show the inputs when selected. Would this work for your case?

The action of filling in the input box is for the frontend, you can use javascript to interact with the "change" event or use laravel's built-in vuejs
